# Use of "this" keyword in template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, compiler-errors

I have defined a template class, and overloaded an operator, in this way:

```
template<class T = bool>
class SparseMatrix
{
public:
    SparseMatrix(int msize);
    //Multiplication by vectors or matrices
    SparseMatrix<double> operator *(SparseMatrix<T> &s);
    //Matrix exponentiation
    SparseMatrix<double> pow(int n);
};
```

The particular form of the operator is not important, I think. With the operator overloaded, now I can do things like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;

    SparseMatrix<bool> s = SparseMatrix<bool>(4);
    SparseMatrix<bool> t = SparseMatrix<bool>(4);

    //Here goes some code to fill the matrices...

    SparseMatrix<double> u = t*s; //And then use the operator

    return 0;
}
```

This works very well. No error, it returns correct results, etc. But now, I want to fill the `pow` method of the class, in this way:

```
template<class T>
SparseMatrix<double> SparseMatrix<T>::pow(int n)
{
    if (n == 2)
    {
        return (this * this); //ERROR
    }
    else
    {
        int i=0;
        SparseMatrix<double> s = this * this; 

        while (i < n-2)
        {
            s = s * this;
            i++;
        }
        return s;
    }

}
```

However, when I go to the `main` and write something like `SparseMatrix<double> u = t.pow(2);` I get an error saying that `invalid operands of types 'SparseMatrix<bool>*' and 'SparseMatrix<bool>*' to binary 'operator*'`. Multiplication is well defined for `bool` matrices as I said before, so, why is the compiler complaining? Am I doing a bad use of `this`? How can I fix this error?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You seem to forget that `this` is a *pointer* to the object. Should be very obvious if you actually read the error message (which mentions the type `SparseMatrix<bool>*`).

Comment: BTW, all `const` are missing.

Comment: And you'll find it much easier and more efficient if you implement `operator*=()` as well as `operator*()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the object, not the object itself. Dereferincing `this` should do the trick.